# Why doesnt reloading the rows resize the table View Rows correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The tableViews row heights are not sizing themselves correctly, I am trying to get the tableViews row heights to size according to the aspect ratio below is the code I have so far for `cellForRowAt` and for `heightForRowAt`.Also some images are being downloaded twice while others aren't downloaded at all.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reuse", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let downloadURL = URL(string: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row])

    if let image = imageCache.object(forKey: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row] as NSString)
    {
        cell.cellImageView.image = image
    }
    else{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL!, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        let downloadedImage = UIImage(data:data!)
        let aspect = CGFloat((downloadedImage?.size.width)!/(downloadedImage?.size.height)!)
        self.imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage!, forKey: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row] as NSString)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.cellImageView.image = downloadedImage
        cell.cellImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/aspect)
            cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
          //  cell.cellImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.cellImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: aspect)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    return cell
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

UPDATED CODE based on suggestions

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reuse", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let downloadURL = URL(string: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row])

    if let image = imageCache.object(forKey: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row] as NSString)
    {
        cell.cellImageView.image = image
    }
    else{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL!, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        let downloadedImage = UIImage(data:data!)
        let aspect = CGFloat((downloadedImage?.size.width)!/(downloadedImage?.size.height)!)
        self.imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage!, forKey: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row] as NSString)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.cellImageView.image = downloadedImage
            cell.cellImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.cellImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: aspect).isActive = true
            cell.imageHeight.constant = (cell.bounds.width * (cell.cellImageView.image?.size.height)!)/(cell.cellImageView.image?.size.width)!
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    return cell
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    print("UITableViewAutomaticDimension: \(UITableViewAutomaticDimension)")
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
}
```

Comment: Just a note but you should never reload anything to do with the table inside cellForRowAt.  If that makes the table dequeue a new cell it will start the whole cycle again.  You need to redesign to avoid having to do this.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth What would be a better design?

Comment: Without looking at the project difficult to say but avoid the reloadRows there.

Comment: you are commenting an important line      //  cell.cellImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.cellImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: aspect)  ,,,,, but it's problem is cellImageView.widthAnchor is not know yet so , replace it with width proportional to screen

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth when I remove the reload rows none of the images are sized correctly

Comment: @Sh_Khan even when its uncommented the rows are still not sized correctly

Comment: You are probably getting away with it at the moment but be careful as it may cause issues.  As for images getting downloaded multiple times are they used in multiple cells or are you scrolling while they are downloading?

Comment: You better keep array of currently  downloading items

Comment: also make it's active property true

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I am scrolling while they download but it should only be one instance of each image. If I dont use the `reloadRows` how can I make sure that the cells are resized correctly.

Comment: There is no way other than what you do but array of currently downloading items and check before makeing the request

Comment: Are you scrolling up and down because if you do you could be requesting the image again before it has downloaded.  As for the resizing I'm not sure without seeing the rest of the project really.

Comment: @Sh_Khan doesn't the imageCache act as a storage mechanism for the images

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth but doesnt the imageCache prevent me from downloading the same image multiple times, should I wait for the images to all load before scrolling?

Comment: no , image cash will not prevent if the item is being downloading and scroll happens as code will go to else so download it again

Comment: If you scroll to a cell it will use the URLSession to download the image but if you scroll up and down before that finishes the cell will need the image again and it won't yet be in the cache.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth so I should wait a few seconds for all the images to download before scrolling through the tableView?

Comment: @Sh_Khan but if I use an array filled with UIImages wont I run into memory issues if too many images are downloaded

Comment: when image downloaded save it with object id and check that object id again in cellForRow , it will give users better experience in your app that cashes images for them cashArr you define is local to the current viewController is poped it will redownload them again , beside keep array of indexpaths current items being downloading to avoid running into memory and redownload again

Comment: @Sh_Khan so create a dictionary using the imageURLs as the key and the images as the values and use that to load images into the table along with the cache still running in the background?

Comment: it depends on current load on device may within seconds app goes to suspended state

Comment: @Sh_Khan But if I create a dictionary and pull from the dictionary and monitor the dictionary’s memory what do I need a cache for

Answer (score 1):

1- Try to save the image and then reload the table

```
  NSString *getImagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",n1.Id]];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:getImagePath])
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
        cell.leftImageV.image =img;
        [cell.activity stopAnimating];
        cell.activity.hidden=YES;
    }
    else
    {

        [cell.activity startAnimating];
         cell.activity.hidden=NO;

        cell.leftImageV.image = nil;

        NSLog(@"xdasdxsadxa %@",n1.mainImgStr);

        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
            __block NSData * imageData  = nil;
            dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{ 

                imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:n1.mainImgStr]];

                //Add the file name
                [imageData writeToFile:getImagePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

            });

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if(imageData)
                { 
                    [self.tableView reloadData];

                } 
            });
        }); 
    }
```

2- regarding aspect ratio , drag the height of the imageView as IBOutlet

and do this in cellForRowAt

```
   cell.imageHeightCon.constant = (cellWidth*imageRealHeight)/imageRealWidth
```

**note:** here i assume that imageview width is equal to cell width ,it's better to give it tableViewWidth in proportional to viewController's view as cellWidth here is not yet rendered say tableView takes full screen width then set cellWidth to self.view.frame.size.width

3- don't forget to put this line before return cell

```
   cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: I save the image files in the `imageCache` initialized to `NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()`  and then I try to reload the rows but it doesnt size the images correctly or list them correctly in the tableView

Comment: anyway , try 2 and 3 in answer